# How to feed a placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a simple feed forward network. However, I can't figure out how to feed a `Placeholder`. This example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

num_input  = 2
num_hidden = 3
num_output = 2

x  = tf.placeholder("float", [num_input, 1])
W_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_hidden, num_input]))
W_out    = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_output, num_hidden]))
b_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_hidden]))
b_out    = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_output]))

h = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(W_hidden,x) + b_hidden)

sess = tf.Session()

with sess.as_default():
    print h.eval()
```

Gives me the following error:

```
  ...
    results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 419, in _do_run
    e.code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape dim { size: 2 } dim { size: 1 }
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[2,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Caused by op u'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "/home/sfalk/workspace/SemEval2016/java/semeval2016-python/slot1_tf.py", line 8, in <module>
    x  = tf.placeholder("float", [num_input, 1])
  ...
```

I have tried

```
tf.assign([tf.Variable(1.0), tf.Variable(1.0)], x)
tf.assign([1.0, 1.0], x)
```

but that does not work apparently.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To feed a placeholder, you use the `feed_dict` argument to `Session.run()` (or `Tensor.eval()`). Let's say you have the following graph, with a placeholder:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, 2])
y = tf.constant([[1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
z = tf.matmul(x, y)
```

If you want to evaluate `z`, you must feed a value for `x`. You can do this as follows:

```
sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(z, feed_dict={x: [[3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]]})
```

For more information, see the [documentation on feeding](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#Feeding).

Comment: Hmm.. is there no other way? That looks inconvenient if I e.g. want to look at intermediary results.

Comment: You can also pass the `feed_dict` argument to `Tensor.eval()`, which might be more convenient when building the graph. If you want a "sticky" placeholder, I'd suggest making your own function that wraps `sess.run()`, captures a set of feed values, and passes that to the `run()` call each time.

Comment: @mrry, could you make an example of your comment? Thanks