# Building new TensorFlow Op, is there a build system standard?

Tags: tensorflow, standards, bazel

After watching this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34247374/1243762) I decided to give writing a new op for TensorFlow a try.

Since the requirements of C++, Python and likely a *nix system are not my primary tools, I would like to avoid being at a point where I have to back out and make a system/tool changes just because I did not ask.

Is there a standard or preferred system and or tools used by those working or TensorFlow?

I know that recommendation questions are not allowed here; I am not asking for a personal recommendation, I am asking for the standard used by or what the TensorFlow group finds that works.

Comment: For problems with Bazel and building TensorFlow look at answers from  [Damien Martin-guillerez](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4717701/damien-martin-guillerez)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, anything where you can get Bazel and the required libraries up and running.  But since you're starting from scratch:  Ubuntu's a very safe bet and (I haven't measured this, but this is a solid estimate) probably gets the most testing and development by the tf team.  But there are many options that all work -- you can develop inside a virtualenv on many environments.  Things like GPU support get a little more platform-specific, and that's where Ubuntu starts to become the easiest choice if you don't have any other constraints.

The key requirements are outlined in [installing Tensorflow from sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources).

Comment: Thanks. I started using Ubuntu after working with TensorFlow, but am using Ubuntu 15.10 which caused me to do some work-arounds, e.g. g++ 5.2 had to downgrade to 4.9.

Comment: Yeah.  I think our Ubuntu testing focuses on 14.04 LTS.

Comment: (Did you report a bug for the problem encountered with 5.2?  That'd be useful to fix.)

Comment: No. I don't even remember if it was due to Bazel, TensorFlow or something else. I will keep an eye out for it if I build a new system. That was when I built it from source several weeks ago.