# Why am I unable to assign to this placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here's a part of the code I am using:

```
subX = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, ())
op1 = tf.assign(subX,x_hat-x)
```

When I execute this code snippet, I get:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'

However, whenever I execute this, it works fine:

```
subX = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((299, 299, 3)))
op1 = tf.assign(subX,x_hat-x)
```

I don't understand why the latter works but not the former. This answer basically says that the Variable requires an initial value, while the placeholder does not. In both cases I am just overwriting them, so why does it matter?
[What's the difference between tf.placeholder and tf.Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693740/whats-the-difference-between-tf-placeholder-and-tf-variable)

Comment: See if this link helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810990/how-to-feed-a-placeholder

Comment: @ranka47 I think I was being ambiguous. The code won't even execute, regardless of any session.run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A placeholder is not meant to be used like this. Instead, it is an input point to your computational graph. You can do something like:

```py
my_var = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
my_const = tf.constant(12.3)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(my_const*my_var, feed_dict={my_var: 45.7})
```

Then, `print(result)` would give the float `562.11005`.

By that I mean that the placeholder (`my_var`, here) is simply a symbolic node representing an input to your computational graph and trying to assign some value to such representation at graph-creation time is conceptually wrong.
If you want to dig deeper in the computational model of Tensorflow you may be interested in [this TF graph explanation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs).

Comment: So simply put it, I can never assign to a placeholder?

Comment: Yes, this is something you don't want to do. Why have you thought of a placeholder for such purpose in the first place? You might be forcing two unrelated dots to join

Comment: I'm just experimenting due to a bug in the code I'm having. For some reason, tf.assign is not giving me the correct output I am looking for